UnboundLocalError disnake
async def callback(self, inter: disnake.ModalInteraction):
    bot = commands.Bot
    embed = disnake.Embed(title="Вам ответили!")
    values = inter.text_values
    id = values[str(id)]
    user1 = bot.get_user(id)
    await user1.send(embed=embed)

ошибка:
await self.callback(interaction)
File "c:\Users\kazti\Desktop\CouponMC BOT'S\cogs\modtools.py", line 277, in callback
id = values[str(id)]
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'id' referenced before assignment


id = values[str(id)]

Ошибка возникает из-за того, что вы пытаетесь присвоить неопределенную переменную id: str(id)

не решило проблему(

в каком смысле не решило? на что вы заменили id?

id = values[id]

у вас в принципе id в values[id] не определено, его нет.
